# How to get user_photo permission app approval on facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I can't seem to get my app approved on facebook for photo approval. The problem is that Facebook says I haven't demonstrated how my app use photos so they can't approve that permission. However I can't show them how my app uses photos because its not approved for users to give that permission! Its a catch-22.

I need to give facebook an account that they can use to connect to my app and see how I pull in user photos. The website is already built using the PHP SDK and its configured to redirect the user to facebook's oauth page where they are prompted for permission. However at this point any username except mine (the developer) sees this:

```
The following permissions have not been approved for use and are not being shown to people using your app: user_photos.
Submit them for review or learn more.
```

So therefore the account cannot grant photo permissions and the app doesn't work right. So facebook won't approve it. How do you get around this catch-22? Things I've tried:

- Creating a facebook test user through their dashboard, it still doesn't have permission to grant photo access
- Creating a real facebook account, uploading photos, and then making that user an "administrator" of my app. Still cannot grant photo access.

This is very frusterating, anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Your App must be created before 30 April 2014 then use it in facebook

Like your AppName Huus then it is created before 30 April 2014 in facebook

Answer (score 1):

This all means you haven't created a test user correctly. If you create a test user from
`https://developers.facebook.com/apps/{your-app-id}/roles/test-users/` (App Settings > Roles > Test Users), the user will have access to any and every permission, even if they've not been approved by Facebook.

When asking for permission, I got no error or warning about unapproved permissions.

[image: Login with Permissions]

I was able to create a test user for my app, logged in and was able to access unapproved permissions. Screenshot is proof.

[image: Example of Test User Permissions]